# How to define compiler directive for a project group in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, conditional-compilation

For example we have 2 project groups - `ProjectGroupA.bpg` и `ProjectGroupB.bpg`. Each group consists of EXE and BPL modules.

In each project group there are same projects `Project1.bpl`, `Project2.bpl`, `Project3.bpl` and different projects `appA.exe`, `Project5.bpl` and `appB.exe`, `Project6.bpl`, like so: ProjectGroupA.bpg (projects exeA-1-2-3-5) and ProjectGroupB.bpg (projects exeB-1-2-3-6).

In the same projects (1, 2, 3) there are minor differences in functionality for application A and B, which are best resolved by using conditional defines (e.g. including certain lines within bpl or uses sections).

Question is - How to set up compiler defines for the project group, so that when application A is built, all modules within it would have directive `DEFINE_PROJECT_A`, and when building application B - directive `DEFINE_PROJECT_B` ?

In case this can't be done, what are possible workarounds for having conditional compilation in a project group? Usage scenario is to be able to change some code on developers machine, hit F9 and see the working application immediately.

Comment: Can't be done and there are no obvious workarounds using the IDE. Deal with this using command line compilation to define the varying conditionals.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Last time I checked, cmd compilation was not working well in D7 (sorry, I can not recall specific details atm, something about paths iirc?). Now I'm looking into including a ver.bpl module into each project, named the same but placed on different paths (`app_a\ver.bpl` and `app_b\ver.bpl`). Then each bpl could have `ver.pas` file, which could contain `const my_version = 'A'` or ` = 'B'` and include it into every project/module that needs it. Then I could write `{$if my_version = 'A'} ... `

Comment: Command line compilation works fine. You just need to do it right. You've got a complex set up here. Frankly, it is silly to attempt to be building from the IDE. Time to face up to that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Building from IDE is part of development process. E.g. when I change some code I want to hit F9 and see the app asap, instead of rebuilding whole project group. Of course build server could be configured in a way that you suggest, but last time I have spent a lot of time and hit a wall with doing it through cmd. We use other approach now (FinalBuilder iirc).

Comment: FinalBuilder calls the command line compiler. They can obviously make it work. For your development needs, you will have to define the conditionals in each project.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "define the conditionals in each project" as I have explained in the question, this is not possible for common projects (1, 2, 3 in example above). Thanks for your time!

Comment: Of course it is possible. When working on app A define the appropriate conditionals in each of the three projects. Then when you switch to app B, change the conditional defines in each of the projects. You'd like to do this at the project group level, but that functionality does not exist. Your disappointment at that state of affairs is not going to change reality.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "When working on app A define the appropriate conditionals in each of the three projects". This is not going to sit well with 50+ projects in each project group and CVS. On a sidenote: solution from my 1st comment seems to work quite well.

Comment: Question says 3 not 50. For you scenario you should script a solution. Build a simple tool. More fundamental though, you entire app design seems flawed.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an include file that is shared amongst the projects, and declare the define there. One drawback (if you see it that way) is that you'll need to use the include in every file that needs to refer to the define.

Other than that, perhaps some IDE expert that can modify the defines for each project in a group?